# How to dynamically create DataFrame names given a list of frames

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a `while` loop to create the subsets of a dataframe.
The output list holds 5 different frames.

I am trying to determine a way where I can dynamically name these frames, without having to type them out as such:
`first_frame = output[1]`

```py
output = []
i = 0
while i < len(int_dict):

     product = df.loc[(df[list(int_dict.key())[i] + ' pct_change' > 90) & (df[list(int_dict.keys())[i]] > 50)]
     output.append(product)
     i += 1 
standouts = pd.concat(output).reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: This will result in unhashable type: 'DataFrame'

Comment: The dictionary keys are the names, the values are the dataframes.